# World rotation with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I rotate an object in world space using THREEJs?

I am not able to make this work, what I am doing wrong?

```
object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
const matrix = object.matrixWorld.makeRotationFromQuaternion( worldQuaternion );
object.setRotationFromMatrix( matrix );
object.updateMatrix();
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `object.rotation.x += 1` ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using transformation matrices, and quaternions? A simple `object.rotation.y = Math.PI` will give you a 180 rotation around the y-axis.

Comment: object.rotation is in local space which will rotate the object relative to its parent node rather than the world/scene

Answer (score 0):

You can get the final local rotation by subtracting the parent rotation.

```js
const parentQuatInvert = object.parent.getWorldQuaternion(new Quaternion()).invert();
object.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(worldQuaternion, parentQuat);
// update matrix etc.
```

If the parent is null, you can just set the quaternion directly with `object.quaternion.copy(worldQuaternion)`